# Making a sum of arrays stop when the number 13 shows up but still return sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am VERY new to Javascript. I tried to look for an answer here but wasn't very lucky and maybe it's how I am asking.  So, now I'm posting.

I have a loop in which I am to get a sum of the arrays.  However, if the number 13 is in the array, then the loop stops adding numbers together but still return the numbers it added before it got to the 13.  Right now, I have this as my code:

```
function sumNumbers(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
    if(array[i] == 13) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I set the argument for the function which is `'array'`. Then I thought I had to create a variable where the sum of the arrays will appear so I started it at `0` (I did try `[]` but tested it and it wasn't correct - still wanting to understand that). I understand that for any loop, you have to have the initialization which was `i = 0`, then the condition and then the final expression.  So, since the number of elements is undefined, I used length. So, it says if the variable i is less than that number then it will keep going and keep adding to it. So I asked it to get a sum of all the arrays but if any number in a array is a `13`, I need it to stop but still return the numbers it added before it reached `13`.

Right now the function is defined, the sum of all arrays are returned and `0` is returned when its empty. But, I get this error

> Expected `16` to deeply equal `3`.

and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help and explain it a little that would be awesome. This is my first question on here, so if I did it in an annoying way, thank you in advance!

Comment: You get what error?  What is the array you're passing in?

Comment: break will only for exit for loop

Comment: I guess it's not really an error, it's just it expected a different answer.  I am assuming I need to put something else after the break so it will still return the sum.  So, like...[1,2,13] would still return 3 rather than returning 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to stop adding when you find 13 and not include 13 in your sum then you need to check on the value of the next array element before you add it to your sum. I reversed two lines in your code. Please see the new version:

```
function sumNumbers (array) {
  // First check if the array is a valid input to this function
  if (typeof array == 'undefined')
      return 0; // Or even better throw an exception

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == 13) { break; }
      sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Also for your explanation. Much appreciated!

Comment: @CharlieLily You are welcome and happy to help. We were all beginners once.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

It's like `forEach`, but it stops looping whenever you return true. It was created for scenarios like yours.

```
let total = 0;
[3,7,4,3,2,1,13,44,66,8,408,2].some(num => {
  if (num === 13) return true;
  total += num;
});
console.log(total); //-> 20
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
function sumNumbers (arr) {
    let total = 0;
    arr.some(num => {
      if (num === 13) return true;
      total += num;
    });
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I think you should understand that OP (as he meintioned) is a JavaScript begginer. How to you expect him to easily understand arrow functions, prototype of constructors, strict comparison, etc which you used? Maybe he is just looking for simple solution.

Comment: I'm a self taught developer who learned from reading code I didn't understand. I make no apologies about my answer and if the OP has questions, they can ask and I will gladly help them learn. The point of my answer is that the language has constructs for solving his problem, and he/she should know that.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty ways of doing that... one of them:

```js
function sumNumbers (array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; array[i] != 13; i++) {
      sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

About your:

> Then I thought I had to create a variable where the sum of the arrays will appear so I started it at 0 (I did try [] but tested it and it wasn't correct - still wanting to understand that).

Well, if you make a variable initialize with [] you are setting an empty array. Remember that brackets [] are for arrays always.

Comment: What if 13 never appears in the array?

Comment: I just ran this code as well and it worked.  Also, thank you for the explanation, that totally makes sense.  I made the above answer correct because it was using the break as I needed.  This answer was super helpful though, I like seeing it can be done in different ways.